# Fill the DataSource of a DataGridView with existing Columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to fill the DataSource of a DataGridView using the existing Columns?

I'm trying to set a DataSource to my DataGridView; every time I set my DataSource, it creates new Columns, which is not the expected result.
I want the data to be presented in the existing Columns.

This is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SourcePath", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("SourceFile", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("OutputPath", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("OutputFile", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Belgium" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "France" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Germany" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Spain" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Switzerland" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "United Kingdom" });

datagridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the DataSource of a DataGridView is set or changed, the default behavior is to generate Columns using the names of the Columns in the data source, since the [AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns) property defaults to `true`.
See the Remarks section in the Docs about this property.

If DataGridViewColumns have been added in the Designer, the [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname) property of each Column is compared to the name of the Columns in the data source.
When a match is found, an existing DataGridViewColumns is bound to the matching Column in the data source. Otherwise a new Column is added to the grid.
In other words - as this appears to be what the OP describes - when Columns are added in the Designer without a `DataPropertyName` and a new DataSource is set, the Columns in the DataSource are added to those already present in the grid.

If the `DataPropertyName` of a DataGridViewColumn is not specified in the Designer, you can set it in code before assigning the `DataSource` property. For example:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourcePath", typeof(string)) { Caption = "Source Path"});  
// [...]

dt.Rows.Add(new[] { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Belgium" });
// [...]

// Assuming DGV Columns are added in the Designer without a DataPropertyName set
datagridview.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName
datagridview.Columns[0].HeaderText = dt.Columns[0].Caption

// Or in different ways, e.g.: 
datagridview.Columns["SourcePath"].DataPropertyName = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName
datagridview.Columns["SourcePath"].HeaderText = dt.Columns[0].Caption
// [...]

datagridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: setting the DataPropertyName  worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The syntax Might be causing it.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SourcePath", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SourceFile", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("OutputPath", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("OutputFile", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));


  
    var Row = dt.NewRow(); //Create a new row
    Row["SourcePath"] = "Test";//Add Column value via Indexer
    //Add Rest of Column Values

    dt.Rows.Add(Row); //Append to Table Rows
```

Comment: The syntax in the OP is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the grid to generate columns it finds In the DataSource and seems to be missing from itself, set

```
datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

before you set the DataSource